# Enum conversion to String not working on @Indexed unique field

Tags: spring-data-neo4j

I'm a Neo4j/Spring-data newbie so apologies if this is something obvious but I looked here and there and can't quite figure out if it's a bug or feature.
I'm using SDN 3.1.0 and Neo4j 2.0.4, running in memory for now (for testing).

I have a super simple POJO that I try to save into Neo4j using SDN. It looks like so:

```
@NodeEntity
public class Weekday {

@GraphId
private Long id;

@Indexed(unique = true)
public DayOfWeek weekdayCode;
}
```

Everything works beautifully when I make it non-uniquely indexed, or not indexed at all. It works fine with unique constraint when I make it a String as well. (Well, sort of, I'm aware that it doesn't throw an exception but silently updates existing one - this is not perfect but I found JIRA issue related to that). Unfortunately the moment I try to save it as enum with unique constraint I get an exception:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: Error executing statement MERGE (n:`Weekday` {`weekdayCode`: {value}}) ON CREATE SET n={props}  return n; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: Error executing statement MERGE (n:`Weekday` {`weekdayCode`: {value}}) ON CREATE SET n={props}  return n; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: [MONDAY:java.time.DayOfWeek] is not a supported property value
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.query.CypherQueryEngineImpl.query(CypherQueryEngineImpl.java:61)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.schema.SchemaIndexProvider.merge(SchemaIndexProvider.java:114)
at [...]
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: Error executing statement MERGE (n:`Weekday` {`weekdayCode`: {value}}) ON CREATE SET n={props}  return n; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: [MONDAY:java.time.DayOfWeek] is not a supported property value
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.query.CypherQueryEngineImpl.parseAndExecuteQuery(CypherQueryEngineImpl.java:72)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.query.CypherQueryEngineImpl.query(CypherQueryEngineImpl.java:58)
... 63 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: [MONDAY:java.time.DayOfWeek] is not a supported property value
at org.neo4j.kernel.api.properties.PropertyConversion.convertProperty(PropertyConversion.java:107)
at org.neo4j.kernel.api.properties.Property.property(Property.java:51)
at [...]
```

This, as far as I can see, is because the unique field is put into a map "props", and the contents of the map is not automatically converted so it sends an enum to Neo4j, which obviously it doesn't like.

1. Is this expected or should I raise a bug with SDN?
2. If that's expected behaviour, do I have any alternatives other than making the field a String?

Comment: Is this considered to be a bug? I know that for example spring-data-mongodb does an automatic conversion.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if it is a real bug, however I had a similar problem using my own Enum class.

So, you could try something like this:

1. Create the converters
2. Register them in neo4j

First create your converters like:

```
@Component
public class StringToDayOfWeekConverter implements Converter<String, DayOfWeek> {

    @Override
    public DayOfWeek convert(String source) {
        return DayOfWeek.valueOf(source);
    }
}

@Component
public class DayOfWeekToStringConverter implements Converter<DayOfWeek, String> {

    @Override
    public String convert(DayOfWeek source) {
        return source.name();
    }

}
```

Then you register the converters, so neo4j can use them:

```
@Configuration
@EnableNeo4jRepositories("my.repository.package")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class MyNeo4jConfiguration extends Neo4jConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private StringToDayOfWeekConverter stringToDayOfWeekConverter;

    @Autowired
    private DayOfWeekToStringConverter dayOfWeekToStringConverter;


    @Override
    protected ConversionService neo4jConversionService() throws Exception {
        ConverterRegistry converterRegistry = (ConverterRegistry) super.neo4jConversionService();
        converterRegistry.addConverter(stringToDayOfWeekConverter);
        converterRegistry.addConverter(dayOfWeekToStringConverter);
        return (ConversionService) converterRegistry;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

create an converter extends EnumStringConverter such like this:

```
package com.noopu.pyramid.domain.model.converter;

import com..pyramid.common.UserType;
import org.neo4j.ogm.typeconversion.EnumStringConverter;
public class UserTypeStringConverter extends EnumStringConverter {

    public UserTypeStringConverter ( ) {
        super ( UserType.class );
    }
}
```

and used @Converter annotation like under:

```
package com.noopu.pyramid.domain.model;

import com.noopu.pyramid.common.UserType;
import com.noopu.pyramid.domain.model.converter.UserTypeStringConverter;
import lombok.Data;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.GraphId;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.Index;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.NodeEntity;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.typeconversion.Convert;

import java.io.Serializable;


@NodeEntity
@Data
public class User  implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8979348201709416439L;

    @GraphId
    private Long graphId;

    @Index
    protected Long id;

    @Index(unique = true)
    private Long uid;

    @Index(unique = true)
    private String phone;

    @Index
    @Convert(UserTypeStringConverter.class)
    private UserType type;

}
```

Comment: I suggest you to improve your example by reading the [Minimal, Complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).